# ¿Cómo hacer un break dentro de un array.forEach en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2015

¿De qué manera se puede hacer un `break` de un `Array.forEach` en JavaScript?
Cuando se utiliza un ciclo "for" en JavaScript el `break` se utiliza para interrumpir el ciclo.

A partir de `ECMA 5.1` aparece la posibilidad de utilizar `Array.forEach` para iterar sobre `array`, pero ¿Cómo se puede hacer un `break` en este tipo de ciclos?

Veamos dos ejemplos, en donde el intento de interrumpir el ciclo Array.forEach con `"return"` no da el resultado esperado:

```js
const firstElems_LenOne_V1 = (arr) => {
  let rta = []
  for (let i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {
    let e=arr[i] 
    if (e.length>1) break 
    rta.push(e)
  }
  return rta
}

const firstElems_LenOne_V2 = (arr) => {
  let rta = []
  arr.forEach(e=>{
    if (e.length==1) return  // break forEach?
    rta.push(e)
  })
  return rta
}

let v1= firstElems_LenOne_V1(["a","b","cc","d"]) 
let v2= firstElems_LenOne_V2(["a","b","cc","d"]) 

console.log(v1)  // OK: expect [a,b] got [a,b]
console.log(v2)  // KO: expect [a,b] got [cc]
```

¿Cómo hacer un `break` dentro de un array.forEach en Javascript?

Comment: No hay `break` para `forEach`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La documentación de [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) tiene una **nota** donde aclara que no hay forma de detener o cortar un  `forEach` a menos que sea una `Exception` , si desea realizar esto el método `forEach` no sería lo adecuado. En su lugar recomiendan emplear [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/some) si necesita devolver un valor `boleano` o simplemente una iteración simple como para este caso.

**Exception** *personalizada*

```js
function BreakException(message) {
   this.message = message;
   this.name = 'Exception';
}

const firstElems_LenOne_V2 = (arr) => {
    let rta = []
    try {
       arr.forEach(e=>{
        if (e.length===1) throw new BreakException('Valor ' + e + ' con Length diferente a 1');
        rta.push(e)
      })
    } catch (e) {
       console.log(e.message); 
    }
    return rta
}
let v1= firstElems_LenOne_V2(["aa","b","cc","d"])
console.log(v1);
```

Answer (score 3):

El método `Array.forEach` no provee un sistema para detener la iteración. Sin embargo puedes usar la función `Array.some` donde puedes devolver `false` para hacer justo lo que quieres.

Ejemplo:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ,'e', 'f'].some(function(item, index){
    console.log(index, item)
    return index === 3;
});
```

Resultado:

```
0 "a"
1 "b"
2 "c"
3 "d"
```